# ArrayList: Getting a String element within an String element?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList here that contains X number of String elements that also contain their own X number of String elements. As such:

```
[ [ c, in,  h,  i, t , n , at, Th,  t, th, ha, e , he, ca],
  [ c, t ,  m, sa,  o, n , at,  s, Th,  t, th, ma, e , he, ca, on], 
  [ a,  b, in,  i, bl, gs, s , an, et, n , la, Pi, ke, nk, ig, a ] ]
```

I need to get a specific element within the element. e.g. List at `[0][0]` would be `c`, `[0][1]` would be `in` and etc... `List.get()` doesn't appear to be working for me. I'm not sure what is the correct way to do that. I saw in another example using `List.get(0)[0]` but its not working for me.

Eclipse is saying `"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"` when I try `List.get(0)[0]`. So I tried `List.toArray()` which didn't help.

EDIT

```
HashSet<String> shingleTrimSet = new HashSet<String>();
ArrayList<String> shingleArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

System.out.println("\nSorted Shingles:");

for(int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++){
    shingleTrimSet.clear();

    for(int idx = 0, jdx = 1; idx+1 < lines[i].length(); idx++, jdx++){
        shingleTrimSet.add( lines[i].substring( idx, jdx+1 ) );
    }
    shingleArrayList.add(i, shingleTrimSet.toString() );

}
System.out.println( shingleArrayList.get(0).get(0) );
```

Right now I'm just trying to get a specific element in the print line. I'm planning to write a for loop that will look for matching substrings from one element to another. I'm doing Jaccard Similarity.

Comment: Could you post more of your code, particularly the way in which you declare and populate the ArrayList

Comment: How did you initiate List? Plz show more code

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you have a list of lists of Strings `List<List<String>> test` then `test.get(0).get(0)` will return the first String in the first sub-list.

Comment: Its not a List<List<String>> though. Eclipse says `"The method get(int) is undefined for the type String"` when I try that. `List<String> list = new List<String>();` The main contents of my ArrayList used to be in a HashSet. I did `list.add(i, set.toString() );` in a forLoop to fill my ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, it sounds like you want to split your strings. Given an initialized variable *strings* declared as:

```
ArrayList<String> strings;
```

the following code will likely suit your needs:

```
for (String s: strings) {
    String[] parts = s.split(",");
    String part2 = parts[1].trim(); // "in" for your first row
}
```

Or maybe you wanted to gather the split fields into a list of string arrays:

```
ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<String[]>();
for (String s: strings) {
    String[] fields = s.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++)
        fields[i] = fields[i].trim();
    rows.add(fields);
}
```

which you can now access as you originally intended:

```
String row1field2 = rows.get(0)[1]; // "in"
```

Comment: How can I implement this without hard-coding separate arrays? My program is reading from a file.txt which could contain any number of lines.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about hard-coding separate arrays. In any case, I added another option to my answer that might be what you're looking for.